# Getting index of each component inside Vue's slots

Tags: vue.js

Imagine I have the following template in my components. `<slot/>` takes in any type of components be it `input type=text`, `label` etc.

```
<template>
  <div :class="field">
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

How do I get an index or counter from each slot component? For example, the first component will have an index of 0, second will have index of 1 etc.

The index will be useful for Rails integration like nested form where each field (Within Rails) needs to  be indexed.

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are trying to do? What do you need the index for?

Comment: Thanks! I added the reason. "The index will be useful for Rails integration like nested form where each field (Within Rails) needs to be indexed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the slots information using the `$slots` keyword

For example add this in the script part of your component

```
created() {
  console.log(this.$slots);
},
```

You will get an object with all the slots of your component

```
{
 // if you create named slot this will be the name of your slot instead
 // default is the name of default slot (same as your case)
 default: [
   // All the elements of the default slot will be there
   // Each entry is an element
   0: {
     ...
   },
   ...
 ]
}
```

I hope this will help you to find the slot info that you want.

If you need more explanation of the `$slots` keyword check this page https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots

Comment: Thanks! Your method provides me  with the array of components but not the index. And for some reason, the this.$slots contains unknown Vnodes. I use a .filter method to clear those unknown  Vnodes and use an inject/provide way to pass this filtered array to each component. How do you propose that each slot component knows its index? Iterate through the array again? Because if i have 100 slot components, i may need to iterate 100 times through the same array. Or do you have other suggestion?Thanks again for helping me move forward

Comment: I think you can try to iterate through every components and try to find the `_uid` key that is the id of components. However the uid of components are not `0,1,...` they are provided by VueJS instance and can be totaly differents, for example the first can have the uid 33 and the second 45. I think the way you can use is to iterate through the array of slot elements and use the keys provided inside this array that would be `0,1,...`. This array is also ordered by elements apparition. If you even have nested elements try to make a recursive function.

Comment: This issue seems to imply the uid is not retrievable https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8350

I'm able to retrieve the uid of the component itself. But how do you get the uid of the VNode? I'm able to see it from console but unable to retrieve it. I plan to generate a hash key/values

Comment: i stand corrected. It is available via `this.$parent.$children[0].uid`